# Drill Down on a specific API in Grafana

Tags: json, graphite, grafana

I've got my data source as Graphite and am using Grafana to stream my results. So imagine I've got a graph that's showing some metrics for 10 APIs I've got.
Now, when I click on one of the API's values on the graph, I'd essentially like a drill down graph panel to open right below with all the metrics pertaining to that particular metric over the past, say, 1 month.

In Graphite, I've got all the data to do this, but I don't know how to pull it off in Grafana. I have a JSON structure to create this drill down graph but I don't know how to parameterize it such that, when a user clicks on a particular API, the stats for THAT API will show up in the drilldown.

Any suggestions?

Comment: I don't fully understand your question but it sounds like you want to go in the direction of "scripted dashboards" http://docs.grafana.org/reference/scripting/

Comment: I've had a look through scripted dashboards but I'm still unclear on how to fetch data based on a click. For example, if I have a bar graph with 10 bars on it, each bar representing an API's response time (for example). When I click on a particular bar, I'm not sure how to generate a drill down for that particular API.